# Cypress: is it possible to extract zip-archive & validate content of files inside it?

Tags: validation, testing, automated-tests, zip, cypress

Test-case is:

1. Login
2. Download the zip-archive
3. Extract it (4 files)
4. Validate fileContent inside them

My failed code is:

```
const decompress = require('decompress');

    decompress('C:/Users/Admin/QA/cypress/downloads/test.zip', 'C:/Users/Admin/QA/cypress/downloads');
    
    cy.readFile('C:/Users/Admin/QA/cypress/downloads/firstFile.c').then((fileContent) => {
      const expectedContent = `some code to validate`;
      expect(fileContent.trim()).to.equal(expectedContent.trim());
```

Faced with an error:

```
(uncaught exception)TypeError: fs$readFile is not a function
TypeError
The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress. It was caused by an unhandled promise rejection.



  > fs$readFile is not a function



When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.
node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:118:1
```

Where I did a mistake? Found the same idea of test https://github.com/MMCampos1703/unzipCypress but it also doesn't work

reinstalled cypress, updated dependencies, used ai to analyze code, searched the same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Of course, this should work, but please make sure that file path, and whether you use the function as Cypress task**

Otherwise what we followed is we use a plugin there and we can get these extracted zip/war files.

dependency : `extract-zip` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-zip
So in our /cypress.config.js

```
const extract = require("extract-zip");
/**
 * Extract zip / war files using extract- zip npm dependency.
 * @param {*} source directory where zip/war file is located.
 * @param {*} target where to need extract the zipped / war file.
 */
async function extractZip(source, target) {
    try {
        await extract(source, { dir: target });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Oops: extractZip failed.", err);
    }
}

const zippedFiles = [];

const unzipFiles = async function (dirPath) {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);

    await Promise.all(
        files.map(async (file) => {
            if (fs.statSync(dirPath + "/" + file).isDirectory()) {
                await unzipFiles(dirPath + "/" + file);
            } else {
                const fullFilePath = path.join(dirPath, "/", file);
                const zipFolderName = file.replace(".zip", "");
                const warFolderName = file.replace(".war", "");
                if (file.endsWith(".zip")) {
                    zippedFiles.push(zipFolderName);
                    await extractZip(fullFilePath, path.join(dirPath, "/"));
                    await unzipFiles(path.join(dirPath, "/", zipFolderName));
                }
                if (file.endsWith(".war")) {
                    zippedFiles.push(warFolderName);
                    await extractZip(fullFilePath, path.join(dirPath, "/", warFolderName));
                    await unzipFiles(path.join(dirPath, "/", warFolderName));
                }
            }
        })
    );
};

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
       /**
                 * This plugin is used to extract zipped files. 
                 * @param {*} dirPath The source, target directory where zipped files 
                 */
                extractZipFiles(zippedFilePath) {

                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        const OUTPUT_DIR = process.cwd() + zippedFilePath;
                        const source = process.cwd() + zippedFilePath;
                        const target = OUTPUT_DIR;
                        extractZip(source, target);
                        unzipFiles(target);
                        resolve(false);
                    });
                },
      });
    },
    
  },
});
```

And how we use this, in the spec file this is how we use this

```
cy.task('extractZipFiles, '<zipFileLocation>');
```

Comment: Thanks. Forgot about cy.task registration as setupNodeEvents